# Java web service sharing a jar file on the Tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jar, war

Busy developing Java Web Services using Eclipse.  We have different environment, we have to deploy each web service on. And each environment has there own unique Environment variables.

I trying to make a jar file with one class `EnvironmentVariables` that will sit on the tomcat server of each environment.

And the Web Services will share this jar file.

So the idea is we develop one Web Service war file, that we can deploy to all environments. And the web services gets its need Environment Variables from this jar file.

But up until now did does not seem to work if we put the EnvironmentVariables.Jar file in the lib directory of tomcat.

It seem to some how include the EnvironmentVariables.jar with it, in the war file. So all environments get the same Environment Variables, which is not what we want, we want each to have its on Environment Variables.

We using Tomcat 7

**EDIT**

Tried deleting the jar file from Tomcat's lib folder and it still runs even after restart Tomcat. Is it possible that another Jar my have it included? How can find out which one?

Comment: $CATALINA_BASE/lib is parsed by the classloader, so it has to work. See the documentation http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html.

Comment: Check the catalina.properties in your eclipse-->servers--->Tomcatlocalhosting--catalina.properties

Comment: We did a test, copy the EnvironmentVariables.jar to tomcat, and local library on our develop machine. Create the war file, deployed it on tomcat. Then we change the EnvironmentVariables.jar but the web service still uses the old EnvironmentVariables.jar. Even if we restart tomcat.

Comment: @Murali What am I looking for in catalina.properties file?

Comment: @Murali if you refereeing to the `common.loader` property `${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar` is there and this should be all I need?